# Can PostgreSQL results include the query?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I run the following command to run 2 queries in a sql file. Could be 1, could be 50 queries. Depends on the deployment.

```
psql -U <username> -h <servername> -d <databasename> -f
20140701_Queries.sql > 20140701_Results.txt
```

Here are the queries:

```
select max(day) from tbl1;
select max(day) from tbl2;
```

Here are the results I get:

```
    max
------------
 2014-06-02
(1 row)

    max
------------
 2014-06-06
(1 row)
```

I would rather it come out something like this:

```
select max(day) from tbl1;

        max
    ------------
     2014-06-02
    (1 row)

select max(day) from tbl2;
        max
    ------------
     2014-06-06
    (1 row)
```

But the exact formatting isn't important right now. Just that someone can look for their query and see their results.

Thanks in advance :)

-- Edit

If I just paste the two queries into psql, I get this mix of results and my input which would be fine, if I could just output it to a file:

```
db=# select max(day) from tbl1;
    max
------------
 2014-06-02
(1 row)

db=# select max(day) from tbl2;
    max
------------
 2014-06-06
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-e` flag when you start psql.
For example:

```
psql -e mydatabase
```

Or, in case of using a script, try the `-a` flag.
[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

Comment: psql -U <username> -h <servername> -d <databasename> -f
20140701_Queries.sql > 20140701_Results.txt -e

That does it. I expected there was an option, I just wasn't finding it. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, @ShawnMTherrien!  I learned something myself.

Thanks for the edit, @Erwin Brandstetter.  As you've noticed, I'm new here.